# What notepad++ command to make all brand names at end go to start

Tags: notepad++

For example:

IWME147 Integrated Washing Machine",Indesit
BHWMD742 Integrated Washing Machine",Hotpoint
IWE81681 ECO Washing Machine",Samsung

Becomes:

Indesit IWME147 Integrated Washing Machine"
Hotpoint BHWMD742 Integrated Washing Machine"
Samsung IWE81681 ECO Washing Machine"

Find / Replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a regular expression for this, try this:

[image]

Make sure to enable the **Regular expression** checkbox!

```
Find what: (.+),(.+)
Replace with: $2 $1
Check regular expressions
Press "Replace All"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I am not very good at these sort of things. Are you able to give the find and replace commands that would then sort the example lines above?

Comment: You cannot sort with a regular expressions based search and replace, but there is a notepad++ plugin for that. I haven't used it though. http://milospjanic.blogspot.de/2011/05/sorting-lines-in-notepad.html

Comment: I believe you can, as another query I had earlier had a colour and different brand at the end of each one, and the person showed me how to make the colour and brand go to the start. This one is just for the brand, but I don't know the command to use.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want ... you cannot sort lines using regular expressions. What you can do is change the order of string within the lines. This is what the screenshot shows. I achieved exactly your desired result (using your example from the question).

Comment: What was it you wrote in the find / replace to make:

IWME147 Integrated Washing Machine",Indesit   turn into  Indesit IWME147 Integrated Washing Machine"

That is what I need, and for it to do the same on all. Make the brand Indesit, Hotpoint etc, go to the start of each line.

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe you cannot see the screenshot? It's all there.